# How to get Most Recent Version of Java Through Batch

Tags: java, batch-file, directory

I have to create a batch program that verifies a correct JDK install. I have already created a simple java program that, when run, outputs conformation that the JDK has been installed. The program must also, however, set the path to the new JDK. I know that the java file will be in `c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_##\bin`, where ## is one of about 10 diffrent numbers. Is there any way I can search the directory `c:\Program Files\java` for folders beginning with `jdk1.8.0` such that I could set a variable to the appropriate filename? There are other files in the `c:\Program Files\java` directoy, including previous JDKs and JREs.

```
echo Initializing...
set current=%cd% //get current directory
cd c:\Program Files\java //navigate to java directory
set java= //Files formated jdk1.8.0_...
cd %current% //return directory to local (JavaDemo is located here)
set path=%java% //Set path for javac
javac JavaDemo.java //compile JavaDemo
java JavaDemo //run JavaDemo
```

Thanks in advance! Know you guys are a huge help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the dir command with sort options : [dir command](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dir.mspx?mfr=true)

and go through the results with :

```
for /F %%x in ('dir /B/D %MYDIR%') do ( set PATH=%MYDIR%)
```

and choose the right one with a if statement

Comment: If my answer is unsatisfying after more than one year. At least can we know what's wrong with it and what more do you need?